# How do I minimize and maximize a WinForms form without losing my CefSharp browser?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

I have a CefSharp browser added as a control to a WinForms panel. This is fine on first load - the browser works as expected.

This application is regularly minimized to the taskbar, which is done by calling hide() and show() on the form. This works fine for the form, and worked fine with an embedded Internet Explorer browser (the default WebBrowser control)

However, when I hide/show the form, the CefSharp browser doesn't seem to be re-drawn along with the Form. Right clicking where the browser should be shows the Form's context menu, rather than the browser's context menu, which suggests to me the browser is not attached to that form, rather than the webpage within the browser is being incorrectly drawn.

I initially assumed that it was being invalidated and needed to be redrawn, and have tried a variety of `Show, Invalidate, Refresh, Update` method calls on the Form, the Panel, and the Browser itself. I've also tried clearing the panel controls and adding the browser again... none of these things seem to work.

When debugging, the browser object is present, has the same URL and parent, is still showing "fill" as the dock mode, has sensible looking height/width sizes etc, so it doesn't look as though it's been detached in some way from the parent etc, it's just not being re-drawn when the form is shown again

Is there a "correct" method for hiding and showing a form containing a CefSharp browser, or some other way of forcing the browser to redraw, that I'm missing?

Comment: First `minimized to the taskbar, which is done by calling hide() and show()` you do not minimize forms by calling `Hide()` nor do you show a form by calling `Show()`, use the [Form.WindowState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.windowstate?view=netframework-4.7.2) property... Try that and see what happens... If your intentions are to indeed hide and or show the form, then the methods are fine, but according to your post this isn't what you want to do.

Comment: Also have you tried refreshing the [browser](https://cefsharp.github.io/api/63.0.0/html/M_CefSharp_WebBrowserExtensions_Reload_1.htm) itself?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ If I remove the `Show()` and `Hide()` calls, just using WindowState, then I get the same issue (but thanks for the heads up on using the wrong technique for minimizing). I have tried calling Refresh() on the browser itself

Comment: So you are saying when you `minimize` the form and then show it again, the form doesn't show the control/browser even with using the `refresh` method of the CefBrowser, interesting. If that is the case, instead of manually calling these how about you minimize the form yourself and then bring it back, does the browser behave then?

Comment: Precisely. If I set WindowState to FormWindowState.Minimized and then to FormWindowState.Normal, the form doesn't show the browser... although now I've just removed `this.ShowInTaskbar` (set to false then true), and it's working... so it appears to be related to that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So here's my own solution, found with some help from Çöđěxěŕ in the comments (who also points out that using `Show()` and `Hide()` is not the correct way to show/hide a form at all, instead use `WindowState`)

In my case, the problem arose from use of `Form.ShowInTaskbar`

When setting Form.ShowInTaskbar to False (eg don't show the icon for my app when I've just minimized it to the taskbar tray), the browser control seems to get confused about which form is the parent, which appears to be related to the Form.Handle changing.

My solution was to set ShowInTaskBar as false on application load (so the application is never in the taskbar) or not to set it to false on minimize (so it is always in the taskbar when minimized to the system tray). Neither of these are an ideal solution, but they work with the caveat that you have to have the app always hidden, or never hidden.

Presumably it would be possible to re-assign the parent properly on maximize

Comment: `ShowInTaskBar` may seem like it's trivially setting a property, it's far from it under the hood, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20442965/when-showintaskbar-is-false-the-window-disappears/20443430#20443430

It's not currently supported in `CefSharp` see https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/2042

Comment: Thanks, that explains the problem perfectly - as you say, it appears trivial until you run into a strange interaction like this one

Answer (score 0):

Use 
this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
[Please see the scrrenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3866n.png)